# Getting unique values from a CSV

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, active-directory

I have 2 CSV's. One is a list of accounts ($filename2), and the other is a list of accounts I don't want to be in the first list ($excludelist).

I am trying to use compare-object to just grab the unique values from the first list, however I have noticed some of the values in the second list are there as well. Can someone please take a look at this section of code and help me figure out where I went wrong?

```
$filename3 = "FinalDoc"
$excludelist = "ExcludeList"
$exclude = import-csv $excludelist
$include = import-csv $filename2
Compare-Object $exclude $include -property UserPrincipalName,ObjectId | where-object {$_.SideIndicator -like "=>"} | export-csv $filename3
```

Comment: Do you need to check if both values `UserPrincipalName` and `ObjectId` are not present in the `$excludeList` or is it just `UserPrincipalName` or `ObjectId`. Seems like this could be as simple as `$include | Where-Object { $_.UserPrincipalName -notin $exclude.UserPrincipalName }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **problem**:

When you use [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) with `-Property`, the elements of the two input collections are compared by *all* given properties.

- As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out, it should be sufficient to compare by *either* `UserPrincipalName` *or* `ObjectId`, as either value uniquely identifies a user.

However, presumably you *also* used `-Property` to  *select the output properties*.

- Indeed, by default you get `[pscustomobject]` instances that contain only the properties specified via `-Property`, alongside a `.SideIndicator` property indicating which collection the property-value combination is unique to.

By default, you cannot *separate* these aspects: any desired output properties invariably participate in the comparison, which fails if only the elements of *one* collection have all desired output properties, for instance.

The **solution**:

- The `-PassThru` switch changes the output behavior to emitting the *whole input objects* instead of only the `-Property` values.

  - The objects still have a `.SideIndicator` property, which is added as a `NoteProperty` member via PowerShell's [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763).
  - Note that if you request inclusion of elements that compare *equal* with `-IncludeEqual`, it is the element from the `-ReferenceObject` collection that is passed through for each matching pair of objects.
- You can then perform the output property selection later, using [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object):

```bash
# Compare by UserPrincipalName only, but pass all original arguments
# through with -PassThru. Then select the output properties with Select-Object
Compare-Object -PassThru $exclude $include -Property UserPrincipalName | 
  Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=>' | 
  Select-Object UserPrincipalName, ObjectId
  Export-Csv $filename3
```